# How to get client ip from node.js express application deployed on AWS Elastic beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, http-proxy

I am using **elastic beanstalk** with **ngnix** proxy server. my application code was on node.js **express** framework. I am trying to access client ip via following code

```js
var ip = event.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || 
     event.connection.remoteAddress || 
     event.socket.remoteAddress ||
     event.connection.socket.remoteAddress;
```

but i always getting same client ip for all incoming request. I think it will be the proxy server's ip address.

How to access real client address from my application???

Answer (score 4):

I defer with @austince, the Client IP will be the ***first*** entry in the list for Elastic Beanstalk.

**Example**:

> X-Forwarded-For: 182.12.12.123, 78.13.13.123

In case anyone, come looking for example code, here is what I have used in my project.

```js
const _ = require('lodash');
const ipAddress = _.split(req.header('X-Forwarded-For'), ',');
ipadd = _.trim(_.first(ipAddress));
```

Comment: Have you found any good docs from AWS on this? It's aggrivating that they are so ambiguous...

Comment: @austince This is the behaviour that I have observed in my Elastic Beanstalk instance.

Comment: It's listed first for me too, running AWS Linux 2 with nginx

Answer (score 3):

Here's the guide from AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html#x-forwarded-for

**X-Forwarded-For** works, but is sometimes *a list of IPs* that have been hit along the way. The Client IP should be *the first entry* in the list for Elastic Beanstalk.

**Ex**:

> X-Forwarded-For: client-ip-address, ip-address-1, ip-address-2

Comment: The X-Forwarded-For request header may contain multiple IP addresses that are comma separated. The left-most address is the client IP where the request was first made. This is followed by any subsequent proxy identifiers, in a chain.(From the docs, basically the first address in the list and not the last)